# How to create "combobox" type select/text input in iOS settings bundle plist?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I need to create a multivalue select with the option of typing in a custom value on my app's settings panel. Is that possible?

Note: I am asking about the panel displayed for my app in the iOS settings - not in one of my ViewControllers.

Comment: google is our best friend :) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301681/iPhone-ComboBox

Comment: How do your use your own ViewController in iOS settings?

Comment: Mmhh... when I've used the solution that i linked, i didn't use any particular setting for view controller... perhaps can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the app settings that appear in the iOS settings app.

Comment: ok, no any particular setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it isn't possible. Here's the documentation page that lists the different types of settings you can make available:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html